# Obter um valor da coluna de um ListView asp c# ao clicar no link a

Tags: asp.net, listview

Quero obter e passar para uma outra página um valor da coluna do listView.
Os campos do ListView: ID: 01; Nome: Daniel; Campo: campo;

```
<%# Eval("campo").ToString() == "nada consta" ? "nada consta" : Eval("campo")
+ "<a href='Promocao.aspx'> ... + infos</a>"%>
```

Quando usuário clicar em "... + infos" quero pegar o "ID" e o "Nome" e levar pra outra página.

Comment: Já tentou usar um linkbutton e na URL pegar o valor do ID através do EVAL()?

Comment: Eu editei para melhor explicar o problema @PedroFilipe

Comment: Possível duplicata de [LinkButton com Eval ListView asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307364/linkbutton-com-eval-listview-asp-net)