# LinkButton com Eval ListView asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview

Quero fazer isso

```
<%# Eval("campo1").ToString() == "nada consta" ? "nada consta" : Eval("campo1")%>
```

dentro do linkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl= '<%# 
"~/Promocao.aspx?ID="+Eval("campo2") + 
Eval("campo3")%>'>...+infos</asp:LinkButton>
```

Ou seja, se existir dados em "campo1", exibe os dados. Senão exibe "nada consta". E, havendo dados, ao clicar em linkButton passa pra outra pagina "promocao.aspx" os campo2 e campo3. Do jeito que está,um ao lado do outro, mesmo não tendo dados em "campo1" o LinkButton fica disponível para clique. Além disso, do jeito que está, na URL o campo2 e campo3 ficam juntos.

Comment: estranho a explicação: "Ou seja, se existir campo1," : vamos lá se quer que só aparece o LinkButton se o campo1 existir? como assim, tem como explicar melhor?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Desculpe, a explicação ficou carente de detalhes. Se não for "nada consta" campo1 mostrará os dados, senão não precisa aparecer o linkButton. Se simm, o usuário então clicará em "...+infos" indo para outra pagina, onde irei recuperar os dados do campo2 e campo3 - para montar uma requisição de pagamento - que sempre vão existir, uma vez existindo campo1. Quero também que na URL fique separado os parametros campo2 e campo3 e nao juntos sequencialmente, Um espaço entre eles seria bom.

Comment: Um espaço entre eles seria bom -> não está correto assim, o que você fazer e criar um ID1  e passar o campo3 o que acha?

Comment: Sim @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pode utilizar a propriedade `Visible` do [LinkButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/1cd4z1zs(v=vs.71)) para criticar se o mesmo vai estar presente ou não, ***exemplo***:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>                    
        <div>                        
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
                PostBackUrl='<%#string.Format("~/Promocao.aspx?id={0}&id1={1}", Eval("campo2"),Eval("campo3"))%>' 
                runat="server" 
                Visible='<%#Eval("campo1").ToString()!="nada consta"%>'>
                    Item
            </asp:LinkButton>    
            <asp:Literal 
                ID="Literal1"
                runat="server"
                Text='<%#Eval("campo1").ToString()=="nada consta"?"nada consta":""%>'>
            </asp:Literal>                    
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

e no `PostBackUrl` criar as opções desejadas para resgatar na página da sua configuração.

<sub>***Referencias*** [LinkButton Web Server Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/1cd4z1zs(v=vs.71))</sub>

Comment: Quando consta, no lugar dos dados de campo1 exibe "item".' Não está certo.

Comment: @Daniel não entendi?

Comment: Amigo é um exemplo nem no seu @Daniel tem algo escrito

Comment: Verdade. Eu estou explorando esse exemplo aqui. Quero que apareça os dados e o controle para o usuário poder clicar. Caso não haja dados para exibir, então exiba "nada consta", nesse caso, linkButton não aparece, apenas o texto "nada consta".

Comment: @Daniel está dificil de entender!

Comment: De acordo com excelente exemplo acima, quando nada consta em" campo1" o controle desaparece. Isto está correto. Porém, quero que apareça um texto para o usuário saber que nada consta no campo desse registro. E quando consta, o controle aparece. Isso está correto. Porém, quero que apareça não somente o controle, mas o dado de "campo1".

Comment: @Daniel é só colocar um literal e inverter a informação do visible, fiz a edição.